# Keep getting an error: "UIImagePickerController extension discovery failed with error: (null)"

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I'm trying to use UIImagePickerController.
It used to work fine but suddenly stopped working.

Currently, I have inconsistent results(it sometimes works but sometimes doesn't).
Here are methods related to UIIMagePickerController.

What is wrong?

```
 @IBAction func uploadImageTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let pickerView = UIImagePickerController()

    // Set cameraroll sor chooseing a photo
    // choose '.camera' if you want to take the picture
    pickerView.delegate = self
    pickerView.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    self.present(pickerView, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
.
.
.
extension RetailerProfileViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

// method that will be called when user choose the pic
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
    // get the info of photo
    let image = info[.originalImage] as! UIImage
    // show it
    storeImage.image = image

    // dismiss the photo library
    self.dismiss(animated: true)
}
```

}

Comment: Can you be more specific in relation to what happens / does not happen when the button is pressed?

Comment: When I tap the button, a white screen is presented (which is supposed to be the Image Picker). However, pictures themself aren't presented.

Comment: Sounds like an access problem to me if its being presented. Is the access definitely working correctly?

Comment: Yes, I found out this doesn't work only when I'm using iPhone11 Pro Max. This code works fine with any other simulators.

Answer (score 1):

You can check here.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60397039/12494594

I checked the details, and there are no issues in your implementation. I also checked the apple's official sample here. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/customizing_an_image_picker_controller Same result!

Finally, this is an issue related to iOS Simulators(version 11.3.1). I just want you guys not wasting time on this. Move ahead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try  to make UIImagePickerController a class variable and to create it only once. Don't initialise it on every tap will hopefully resolve your issue
use this code

```
picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) // dismiss picker
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0, execute: {
            storeImage.image = image
        })
```

Comment: Is this the code to put in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method? or in the uploadImageTapped method?

Comment: Didfinish method .. replace self.dismiss with picker.dismiss

Comment: have you found the solution ?