# UIImagePickerController extension discovery failed with error: (null)

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

I'm trying to implement an ImagePicker on my ViewController, but turns out it presents a blank ImagePicker Controller and `UIImagePickerController extension discovery failed with error: (null)` message on the console.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong, and I found no information on the matter. One thing I noticed, though, is that the PickerView takes a little  bit too long to be presented.

The code related to the ImagePicker is the following:

```
private let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

private func setupImagePicker() {
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
        imagePicker.delegate = self
        imagePicker.mediaTypes = ["public.image"]
}

    @objc private func launchImagePicker() {

        let photos = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
        if photos == .notDetermined {
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ [weak self] status in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    if status == .authorized, let picker = self?.imagePicker {
                        self?.present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    } else {
                        self?.present(URealtorUtils.getAlert(message: "You have to authorize photo library access in order to upload a photo"), animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                }
            })
        } else if photos == .authorized {
            present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

extension MyController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController,
                               didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            self.viewModel.setPropertyImage(image)
        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of what I get when the PickerView is presented:

[image]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175009/keep-getting-an-error-uiimagepickercontroller-extension-discovery-failed-with ?

Comment: @matt It could be a duplicate, yes. But this question has no valid answers.

Comment: How do you call your `launchImagePicker()`? Your code seems to be working fine, I tried it.

Comment: @Glenn I have it setup as a target on a UIButton.

Comment: Interesting. You could make a very fresh project and test your code. Start from there. Also, try to clean your project and install a fresh build?

Comment: do you actually call `setupImagePicker`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I checked the details, and there are no issues in your implementation.
I also checked the apple's official sample here.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimagepickercontroller/customizing_an_image_picker_controller
Same result!

Finally, this is an issue related to iOS Simulators(version 11.3.1).
FYI, I found iPhone 11 Pro Max didn't work in some previous versions, but iPhone 8 and some others worked.
I just want you guys not wasting time on this. Move ahead.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi could you include a reference to the statement : "this is an issue related to iOS versions/Simulators" ? It would help

Comment: I'm having this issue on iPhone 8 with iOS 13 on the Simulator. Turns out it worked perfectly fine on the iPhone SE with iOS 13. Crazy simulators. Thank you, @SoftwareEngineer